# Bootstrap Popover - how to add link in text popover?

Tags: html, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

*I use bootstrap 3 popover.*

*And now I would like link on text popvover.*

Code:

```
<a href="#" 
  role="button" 
  class="btn popovers" 
  data-toggle="popover" 
  title="" 
  data-content="test content <a href="" title="test add link">link on content</a>" 
  data-original-title="test title"
  >
  test link
</a>
```

*But when I start code in html I see:*

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn popovers" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="test content &lt;a href=" "="">link on content</a>
" 
data-original-title="test title"
&gt;
test link
```

*I know that problem in symbol `"` but i don't know have add link in link...*

*Tell me please how will be aright code?*

*P.S.: if question already exist please give me link.*

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You'll need to pass `html` option with value `true` while initializing popover like following.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqT5f/2/)

**JS:**

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]")
  .popover({html:true})
```

**HTML:**

```html
<a
  href="#" role="button" class="btn popovers" data-toggle="popover" title=""
  data-content="test content <a href='' title='test add link'>link on content</a>"
  data-original-title="test title" target="_blank"
>
  test link
</a>
```

Comment: This works, but not in combination with "Dismiss on next click" (=attribute data-trigger="focus").

Comment: Is single quotes (') is important inside data-content ?

Comment: Yes I guess so.

Comment: I provided workaround for  "Dismiss on next click" case below.

Answer (score 44):

Simply use the attribute **data-html="true"**.

```
<button
  data-toggle="popover"
  data-content="Link: <a href='xyz.com'>XYZ</a>"
  data-html="true">
  CLICK
</button>
```

Comment: how to add link to <a href="#" role="button" in href part

Answer (score 9):

I used `data-trigger="focus"` and had an issue with a link in content of popover. If mouse button is clicked on the link and hold for a while then the popover disappears and the link 'doesn't work'. Some clients complained about that.

HTML

```html
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn popovers" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="" data-content="test content <a href='/' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-original-title="test title">test link</a>
```

JS

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({html:true})
```

You can reproduce the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vqT5f/801/).

I used the folowing [code](http://jsfiddle.net/vqT5f/813/) to fix the issue:

`data-trigger="manual"` in html and

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]")
    .popover({ html: true})
        .on("focus", function () {
            $(this).popover("show");
        }).on("focusout", function () {
            var _this = this;
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(this).popover("hide");
            }
            else {
                $('.popover').mouseleave(function() {
                    $(_this).popover("hide");
                    $(this).off('mouseleave');
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You saved me with this! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use focus **and** a link inside the popup you need to prevent the popup to close when clicking inside. The cleanest solution I found was to `preventDefault` clicks inside a Popup which has the `.popover` class or any other custom class you define.

```
$('body')
  .on('mousedown', '.popover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  });
```

Comment: You can also simply add a short delay to the popover. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497464/1376661

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="#" class="btn popovers" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="test content <a href='' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-html="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
```

By simply adding data-html="true" is working with link attribute :)

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting that whilst the answers given are correct - a link will cause problems when the `data-trigger="focus"` is applied. As I found out *from a client* if the click occurs quickly on a popover the link will be actioned, should a user hold down their mousebutton then unfortunately the trigger kicks in and the popover occurs. So in short consider whether a link is necessary and plan for slooow clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("mousedown",".my-popover-content a",function(e){
    document.location = e.target.href;
});
```

does it for me: basically, take matters into your own hands. Again, this is with popover options `html: true`, `sanitize: false`, and `trigger : "focus"`