# Get the elements of HTML tags inside data-content of popover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

I am working in the "popover" of Bootstrap3. Here I have placed the HTML contents like below,

```
<a href='#' class='btn' title ='Test' data-trigger='focus' data-
toggle='popover' data-html='true' id = 'testOutside' data-content='<a 
href="#" id="testInside" class="btn">Inside</a>'>Click Here </a>
```

I am not able to refer to the html element present inside the data-content attribute.

Like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

// the below is not working
$('#testInside').click(function(){
alert('Inside');
});

$('#testOutside').click(function(){
alert('Outside');
});
});
```

But the bootstrap classes are getting applied, In this case "btn" is getting applied to the anchor tag. Attaching the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajayvembu/8zs660na/). Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Your question is vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work you have to make sure to add a small `delay` to the popover options, the default value is `0`. Which makes this for some reason impossible to work.

<s>Delete the `data-content` attribute from the link triggering the popover, you don't need that, and it will not work, even if you set the `html` property in the options to `true`.</s>

The next step is to add an event-listener to the triggering element, which will listen for the `inserted.bs.popover` event. This one gets fired when the template is added to the DOM.

At that point you can create an element, add it to the popover and assign your listener for click events to it. You do not have to create the element you could as well just use the `data-content` attribute to add your element.

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) you can find information on Popover.js options and events

---

### Update!

I just found out that it is actually only the delay that is needed. So the Solution mentioned by *Parth Shah* will work as well.

Looks like the hide event of the popover is being trigger before you can click the inside link.

So that is all that is needed

```
$('you-selector').popover({
    delay: 100
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    delay: 100 // this is definitely needed !
  });


  $('#testOutside').click(function(){
    alert('Outside');
    console.log('outside');
  });

});

// Listen for inserted template to DOM
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
  console.log($('.popover-content').find('#testInside'));
  // Create the inside link.
  $inside = $('<a href="#" id="inside">Inside</a>');
  // Add the click event-handler only once
  $inside.one('click', function() {
    alert('Inside');
    console.log('foo');
  });
  $('.popover-content').append($inside[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href='#' class='btn' title ='Test' data-trigger='focus' data-toggle='popover' data-html='true' id = 'testOutside'>Click Here </a>
```

Comment: Attaching the correct answer solution - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajayvembu/8zs660na/2/)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is possible to do it easily using the `shown.bs.popover` trigger. It will be executed after the popover is shown. It is then possible to `add new listeners` or refresh the existing ones.

Javascript

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(
    {html:true}
);

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $('#testInside').click(function(){
        alert('Inside');
    });

    $('#testOutside').click(function(){
        alert('Outside');
    });
})
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' class='btn' title ='Test' data-trigger='focus' data-
toggle='popover' data-html='true' id = 'testOutside' data-content='<a
href="#" id="testInside" class="btn">Inside</a>'>Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When your document is ready, there is no element in the DOM that has an id of testInside. This element is created when you click on #testOutside. Due to this, any event handler you create at `$(document).ready(...)` is useless.

So the proper way of doing this is to register a callback immediately after #testInside is added to the DOM. And we know this happens when #testOuside is clicked on.

```
// adding delay over here due to popover close event may trigger before link click event (which happens in Firefox)
$('you-selector').popover({
    delay: 100
});

$('#testOutside').click(function(){
    $('#testInside').click(function(){
        alert('Inside');
    });

    alert('Outside');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true, even if it seems to be obvious. The string inside the `data-content` attribute is just a string and it gets added with `$.text()` method. But that is not all, event if you force the popup to use `$.html()` it will still not work.

Comment: @DavidDomain I am sorry but I disagree with what you are saying. Here is a JsFiddle demonstrating my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/parthsha/8zs660na/1/

Comment: Copy your fiddle link, open a new browser window and you will see that in chrome it will only work after clicking the trigger a second time and in firefox it does not work at all.

Comment: @DavidDomain you are correct. And I have learnt a new thing today. Thank you sir!

Comment: No problem, happy coding. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Both of your answers are working for me on Chrome browser, but as DavidDomain answer is more detailed and browser independent I am choosing his as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I made a very challenging problem simply possible using **shown.bs.popover** even the thing is i have a rating component on the pophover , but the problem was the rating doesn't get the hover event becuse of this method need to be called on the rating input is created.

```
$(".rating_product").rating('refresh', 
 {showClear: false,hoverEnabled:true,hoverChangeStars:true,showCaption: true,starCaptions: {5.0:'5 Stars'}
 });
```

So i put this and it worked than the inserted function.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {


          $(".rating_product").rating('refresh', 
            {showClear: false,hoverEnabled:true, hoverChangeStars:true,showCaption: true,starCaptions: {5.0:'5 Stars'}
          });

})
```