# Links within jQuery Popover/Tooltip don't work with jQuery SmoothScroll?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to cross-reference a lot of info within the page and found that popovers provide a nice way of de-cluttering links. However, the smooth scrolling works on normal links, but of course doesn't work on links within the popovers (I guess because they don't exist "on document ready").
Here's an MWE (there is a lot of Lorem ipsum to fill up the page) to show what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   // initialise popover
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html:true,
        delay:{hide:2000},
    });

  //Smooth Scroll on anchor links
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#one">Section One</a>
<br />
<a href="#two">Section Two</a>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content='<a href="#one">Section One</a>'>S1</a><br>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content='<a href="#two">Section two with explanations and stuff</a>'>S2</a>
</div>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

<section id="one">Section One</section>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

<section id="two">Section 2</section>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if it is frowned upon in these forums when people answer their own questions, but, although I couldn't find anyone with the same problem and I was genuinely struggling with this question for a few days, I serendipitously found something unrelated and got the inspiration from here: [Get the elements of HTML tags inside data-content of popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496937/get-the-elements-of-html-tags-inside-data-content-of-popover)

So, basically, as I understand it, 
this:

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {});
```

launches the function() when a popover opens and then within that we need another function that would execute smooth scrolling upon clicking any links that are on the page containing the popover now. So, it looks like this:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
        $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
                || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Seems to work for me. It looks ugly, but don't know if creating a custom function SmoothScroll() and then putting it in both places will be of any advantage. Please let me know what you think.