# How to have a link in a tooltip in html

Tags: html

I have an html code like below,

```
<img src="{% static 'img/orange.png' %}" alt="Active Review" align="right" width="22" height="22" title="tooltip" ng-show="vio.orc_display.create_status == 8"/>
```

Including data-content(din't work too)

```
<img src="{% static 'img/orange.png' %}" data-toggle="popover" title="link to siverify" data-content="<a href='{% url 'verification' %}'</a>" alt="Active Review" align="right" width="22" height="22" ng-show="vio.orc_display.create_status == 8"/>
```

The title field gives me plain text tooltip. Is there any way to put a link in the tooltip in html?

For eg., I need to add the link "https://stackoverflow.com/" in the tooltip while I hover over the image specified in the code.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Edited with the code.

Comment: Bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery UI? Plugin?

Comment: Bootstrap would be the priority.

Comment: you can use jquery for this.try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231315/jquery-ui-tooltip-html-with-links

Comment: Looks good. But I want to do in my bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Popover - how add link in text popover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299246/bootstrap-popover-how-add-link-in-text-popover)

Comment: Pass true to the `html` option. Set in `[data-content]`.

Comment: Can you edit data-content in my code? new to html.

Comment: Is the way i used data-content, right?