# Jquery popover on hover stay active so that the content is clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On hover of bootstrap popover, the content is not clickable. The popover disappears immediately after hover.

```
<div class="cin-help" ng-if="!isCinUser">
    <strong><span>Sevrity</span></strong>
    <span ng-show="isHelpTextShown" class="icon-question-circle icon-color text-large cursor-ptr" id="sev1-help" data-trigger="hover" popover-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title='' title='' popover-html="sev1-Note" ></span>
    <div class="hide" id="sev1-Note" ng-show="isHelpTextShown"><span ><a href=&quot;http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Click here...</a></span></div>
</div>
```

The Js code for it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#simplified-form').on('hover','#sev1-help',function(){
        $('#sev1-help').popover({
            html:true,
            content: function() {
                return $('#sev1-Note').html();
            }
        }); 
   });
});
```

I'm unable to get the popover stay on hover so that the link inside is clickable. Can anyone suggest a method?

Comment: Make a working snippet

Comment: Where are the `#severityHelp` and all other `div`s? Also, popover should work, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20299785/863110)

Comment: The popover works, it comes up but disappeard immediately, I want it to stay on hovering on the popover so that user can click the link inside.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/72/

Comment: @ArchanaRamachandran Try this code
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#simplified-form').on('hover','#sev1-help',function(){
        $('#sev1-help').popover({
    html: true,
      trigger: 'hover',
      container: '#sev1-help',
      placement: 'right',
            content: function() {
                return '<div class="box"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></div>'
            }
        }); 
   });
});`