# Way to trigger ngx-bootstrap popover over a link

Tags: angular, hyperlink, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-popover

I want to use `ngx-bootstrap popover` over a link, ones I click on that link, a popover will show in the bottom.

in ngx-bootstrap website: I found that we can use a Button with a custom template in order to show whatever we want inside that popover this way:

```
<ng-template #popTemplate>Just another: {{content}}</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
        [popover]="popTemplate" popoverTitle="Template ref content inside">
  TemplateRef binding
</button>
```

I'm interested to use this `ng-template` example to show in my case user information ones we click on a linked image of that user.

So while trying for example this way I'm not able to trigger this popover:

```
<a href="#" role="button" (click)="popTemplate.show()" placement="bottom">
  <span>
    <img src="urlPhoto"></img>
  </span>
</a>
<ng-template #popTemplate>Here we go
  name: {{user.name}}
</ng-template>
```

I'm looking to do something similar to what we have in this question:

[Bootstrap Popover - how add link in text popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299246/bootstrap-popover-how-add-link-in-text-popover)

but using ngx-bootstrap popover.

Has someone any idea about the proper way to do this ?

Currently I've this error in the console:

[image]

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: I do not see any error in the console. but I have updated and now I see this error in the console: ``Error TypeError: jit_nodeValue10(...). show is not a function`` may be I can try to create a short demo with Stackblitz and reproduce this outside that big project.

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#custom-content-template

Comment: I know it can work using a button but I have a link with the picture of the currently authenticated user in the app, so I have a feature to add user information ones I click on its picture. so I wanted to use a popover component and adapt it, instead of creating a brand new one  by using absolute css positioning and using mouse listener (renderer.listen) when I click outside to hide the component ....

Comment: Have you tried using `[popover]="popTemplate"` on your `a` element?

Comment: yes, I already tried that in place of ``(click)="popTemplate.show()"`` without success. I'll try to reproduce this in a Stackblitz example, that could be more simpler for anyone to test.

Comment: I tried `popover` binding and it works

Comment: @yurzui if you are able to answer that using an example it will be fine, that I can see which mistakes I'm doing, otherwise I'll try to create a demo here and test it.

Comment: Just click on image https://ng-run.com/edit/CsqBXQDLhSBr5gEKUdyp

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
<a href="#" [popover]="popTemplate" role="button"  placement="bottom">
  <span>
    <img src="urlPhoto"></img>
  </span>
</a>
<ng-template #popTemplate>Here we go
  name: {{user.name}}
</ng-template>
```